# Accessing methods of a subclassed QGraphicsRectItem object

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene

I have subclassed the QGraphicsRectItem, named ResizableRectItem. I have added a new member (int index), and two methods (getIndex() and setIndex() ).
I'm adding ResizableRectItems to a QGraphicsScene

```
ResizableRectItem* item1 = new ResizableRectItem(selrect.normalized());
scene()->addItem(item1);
```

Later i have to call the getIndex() method, but i only access the items over the items() of the scene(), but

```
int idx = scene()->items().at(0)->getIndex();
```

is incorrect, because scene()->items() is QGraphicsItem and don't have getIndex() method.
What is the correct solution ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the correct solution?

If you can re-think the logic in your code so that you don't have to depend on the interface of `ResizableRectItem`, that will be best.

If you cannot do that, then, you'll need to use `dynamic_cast`.

```
QGraphicsRectItem* gitem = scene()->items().at(0);
ResizableRectItem* item = dynamic_cast<ResizableRectItem*>(gitem);
if ( item != nullptr )
{
   int idx = item->getIndex();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works (if i write QGraphicsItem instead of QGraphicsRectItem). I've re-think my logic and i noticed, that the QGraphicsItem has a member named data (with getter/setter methods) and i can store arbitrary data in it, so i dont't need to create own member `index`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cast the object to your datatype and on success operate on it. Like that:

```cpp
ResizableRectItem* item = qobject_cast<ResizableRectItem*>(scene()->items().at(0)); 
if (item)
{
   int idx = item->getIndex();
}
```

More Info at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/metaobjects.html